# why can't use the 'link' as a name of class

Tags: c++, class

As the title mentioned. The following code shows error :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class link
{
    public:
        link()
        {
            num=0;
            next=NULL;
        }

        int num; 
        link* next;
};

int main() {
    link test;

    return 0;
}
```

compile this code with

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

my g++ versions is

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

And the compiler shows the following error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘test’
```

If I comment this 'link test' statement, then everything is ok.
Besides, if I replace 'link' with other name like 'Link', everything is ok too.

In **Visual Studio** or **VC**, the code is ok.... So it confused me very much.

Comment: Compiles fine [here](http://ideone.com/ytkmH5).

Comment: What is the command line that you're using to compile?  You're not calling `g++` with something like `-Dlink`, are you?

Comment: With g++ 4.6.3 : `g++ -E file.cpp  | grep link` yields `extern int link (__const char *__from, __const char *__to)` - which seems to result from #include <iostream>.

Comment: @jamesdlin g++ test.cpp -o test

Comment: @BjörnPollex But in g++, it comes wrong...

Comment: Using Ubuntu and same g++ (4.6.3), I am facing same error.

Comment: @Nbr44 awesome! But why there is no confict?

Comment: Based on what @Nbr44 says, it's probably a name clash between a funciton `link` and your class `link`. You'd have to instantiate it as `class link test;`, or rename it. Assuming that function is defined in `std`, the best thing would be to remove `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Angew I think that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Default Yes, but Nbr44 should be the one posting it.

Comment: @Angew one more question, why there is no confict for sharing the same name between class and function? But there is confict between function and variable?

Comment: @Nbr44 I think you should post your findings as an answer with the additions made by Angew and score some reputation

Comment: @alfredtofu C++ allows this, probably for compatibility with C (which has two distinct sets of names: for `struct`s and for everything else). That's why you can still disambiguate by using `class link`; in C, it would actually be mandatory to say `struct link` all the time. That's the origin of the common C idiom `typedef struct S { ... } S;`, which makes `S` a name for `struct S` in the "non-struct" set of names.

Comment: @Angew however, link is not in namespace std... removing using namespace std is useless. the best think is to modify the class name...

Comment: @alfredtofu, you definetly should rename your class, or at least create your own namespace (so you can write something like `alfredtofunamespace::link test;`). Using namespaces in your projects is a good style, you should always do that if not restricted by coding policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments:
GCC includes a *function* named `link`. For C compatibility, C++ allows you to define a struct (or class) with the same name as a function, but you have to disambiguate them on use.

I.e. in this case, the fix is `class link test;`

The use of `link` inside the definition of `class link` is an exception, there it always refers to the class itself. This is necessary to be able to write the constructor, as you can't disambiguate the name there. There's no syntax which would allow it.

Comment: @Nbr44 , his answer should be first, however, it just a comment.. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [int link(const char *path1, const char *path2);](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/link/) function in unistd.h, which appears to be included from iostream. Gcc has had some [problems](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35557) with this kind of problem in the past. (I note that 4.7.2 doesn't show this behavior.)

As noted by MSalters, adding a

```
class link test;
```

should disambiguate the problem.